# Cannot save data containing apostrophe to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, escaping

Having issue when I try to submit data with apostrophe, won't allow me to save into database.

com0 is my form field.

```
$ucom0= mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['com0']);

$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO database(feed1,comp1) VALUES ('".$ucom0."','".$uincrease0."')";
```

and here is the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's
```

Comment: If you use prepared statements, you'll sidestep this issue completely. You're already using mysqli, which supports them.

Comment: This is not the kind of issue one should be sidestepping it's a basis of understanding quoting standards.

Comment: Show the generated query. There's no way $ucom0 could be causing this, so most likely it's $uincrease0

Comment: Could you please give me some example code. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719831/php-sql-insert-error/12719881#12719881

Comment: @MihaiStancu - I'm not sure I follow you. If you're using bound parameters, you don't need to worry about quoting standards because it's all taken care of for you.

Comment: @andrewsi I fully agree that PDO is the tool to use, and that prepared statements are the way to go. But if you don't know how to construct a string across languages - build it in PHP to be executed by SQL, or build it in PHP to be executed by JavaScript. Then your problems will not stop with using prepared statements.

Comment: @MihaiStancu - that is an excellent point.

Comment: everything works fine, only when you type apostrophe give me that error above.

Comment: think about what the code is doing with the variables, if the value of `$uincrease0` is, for example `foo's`, then the statement PHP will create would be: `INSERT INTO database(feed1,comp1) VALUES ('ucom','foo's')`, `'foo's'` is invalid. As others have said, look at using prepared statements to build SQL queries, eg: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 3):

Data with an apostrophe will close the SQL statement prematurely. This is bad and can be open to SQL Injection. You should really use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). However, `mysqli_real_escape_string` can be used.

But the reason this doesn't work is because `mysqli_real_escape_string` requires two parameters when you call it procedurally like you are (unlike the deprecated `mysql_real_escape_string())`;

```
$ucom0= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['com0']);
```

Where `$link` is the variable returned from when you connected to the database:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("databasehost", "username", "password", "database");
```

This will be different if you are using Object based mysqli to connect:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("databasehost", "username", "password", "database");
$ucom0 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['com0']);
```

Comment: on this line my dreamweaver is giving me error: $ucom0= mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['com0']);