# INSERT INTO mysql database not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, insertion

I am trying to do something really simple here. All I want to do is to insert information in MySQL
Here is the code below for the form.

```
 <?php
 $host=""; // Host name 
 $username=""; // Mysql username 
 $password=""; // Mysql password 
 $db_name=""; // Database name 
 $tbl_name=""; // Table name 

 // Connect to server and select database.
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

 // get value of id that sent from address bar
 $dj=$_GET['dj'];

 // Retrieve data from database 
 $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE dj='$dj'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
 $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
 ?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="insert_ac.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Insert The information for the Now PlayingProgram.</strong>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email2</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="email2" type="text" id="email2" value="" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Twitter</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Twitter2</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Avatar</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="twitter" type="text" id="twitter" value="">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="twitter2" type="text" id="twitter2" value="" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="avatar" type="text" id="avatar" value="" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Facebook</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Facebook2</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Type</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="facebook" type="text" id="facebook" value="">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="facebook2" type="text" id="facebook2" value="" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="type" type="text" id="type" value="" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Alias1</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Alias2</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Alias3</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="alias1" type="text" id="alias1" value="">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="alias2" type="text" id="alias2" value="" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="alias3" type="text" id="alias3" value="" size="15">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
 <td colspan="3" align="center"><strong>Request Line</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3" align="center">
 <input name="address" type="text" id="address" value="" size="65">
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>
 <input name="dj" type="hidden" id="dj" value="">
 </td>
 <td align="center">
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
 </td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </td>
 </form>
 </tr>
 </table>
  <?php
 // close connection 
 mysql_close();
 ?>
```

Now what I want to be able to do is to insert the information in the database that I enter in this form. 
Well my issue is when I enter some data and click on submit, all i get is ERROR.

So lets take a look at my incert_ac.php
code is below:

```
<?php
 $host=""; // Host name 
 $username=""; // Mysql username 
 $password=""; // Mysql password 
 $db_name=""; // Database name 
 $tbl_name=""; // Table name 

 // Connect to server and select database.
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

 // Connect to server and select database.
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

 // insert data in mysql database 
 $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (name, email, email2, twitter, twitter2, avatar, facebook, facebook2, type, alias1, alias2, alias3, address, dj)
  VALUES('{$_POST[name]}', '{$_POST[email]}', '{$_POST[email2]}', '{$_POST[twitter]}', '{$_POST[twitter2]}', '{$_POST[avatar]}', '{$_POST[facebook]}', '{$_POST[facebook2]}', '{$_POST[type]}', '{$_POST[alias1]}', '{$_POST[alias2]}', '{$_POST[alias3]}', '{$_POST[address]}', '{$_POST[dj]}')";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);

 // if successfully inserted 
 if($result){
 echo "Successful";
 echo "<BR>";
 echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
 echo "1 record added";
 }

 else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

I would like to know if I am just having a syntax or even a spelling issue here!
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe because your variable `$tbl_name` is always empty

Comment: i removed that infomation for secuity reasons

Comment: Re-check whether all these fields `name, email, email2, twitter, twitter2, avatar, facebook, facebook2, type, alias1, alias2, alias3, address, dj` are exist in the table `$tbl_name`

Comment: To find error, try using `mysql_errno()` and `mysql_error()` and tell us what error mysql returns

Comment: yes all of these fields do exist in the table

Comment: `"$host"`? Cargo-cult programming...

Comment: I have added  mysql_error() and  mysql_errno() and all i get is ERROR because of my else code for if($result)

Comment: You need to add it while querying: ` $result=mysql_query($sql) OR die('Error: '.mysql_error());`

Comment: Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719831/php-sql-insert-error/12719881#12719881

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column names `name` and `type` need to go in tick marks as they are reserved names in MySQL.

Update the `$sql=` lines to the following code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (`name`, email, email2, twitter, twitter2, avatar, facebook, facebook2, `type`, alias1, alias2, alias3, address, dj) VALUES (
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email2'])."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['twitter'])."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['twitter2'])."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['avatar'])."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['facebook'])."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['facebook2'])."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type'])."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['alias1'])."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['alias2'])."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['alias3'])."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address'])."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dj'])."')";
```

**EDIT:** added some SQL input sanitization

Comment: sorry but that did not solve my issue

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL Injection, though. While you're at it, you could correct this wrongness too

Comment: I added some sanitization to the insert statement.

Comment: ok i tried this as well and still did not work

Comment: Try echoing out `$sql` and running through an editor such as mysql workbench so you can see exactly what error is occurring and where in your SQL statement.